# SUMIF look to previous row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to make `SUMIF` in Google Spreadsheets to look at the previous row for its evaluation. So if my sheet looks like this:

```
trigger     value1

something   value2
```

I want it to add value2, because the trigger is in the previous row. Can this be done with `SUMIF` and if not, is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is achieved by shifting the criteria range by one row:

```
=sumif(A2:A15, "<6", B3:B16)
```

sums the entries in B where the number up-and-to-the-left is less than 6.